# Google Plus Login Internal Server Error After creating a signed Release apk

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

I have this weird Issue that When I connect my Device via USB and Run the app in my Device it is working properly and I was able to sign into google plus.

when I generate a signed apk release file and copy that and paste it in my device , after Installation when I try to Login it says Internal server Occured.

PS

I have filled the consent Screen in the developer console , I have entered my androiddebugkey in the Credentials  of the Developer Console as well .

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate Base64 key and sign with package name. submit in Developer console. after complete process you will sign with google.

```
  private void generateHashKey() {

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo                       ("loginwith.gplush.android", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String hashCode  = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                System.out.println("Print the hashKey for Facebook :"+hashCode);
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),          Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android


I did this , I am using Android Studio and Gradle to Build the Release App. The Key I generated is SHA1 how do i generate Base64